# Simpler way to call and API Gateway endpoint with Cognito credentials in Java without generated SDK?

Tags: java, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I do not want to use a generated SDK for my API Gateway endpoint.  I want to use the plain AWS SDK.  When I googled how to do that, nothing obvious came up in the first few hits (surprisingly).  So I cobbled this together:

```
private static void invokeApiGatewayWithCognito(String identityPoolId, String endpoint) throws URISyntaxException {
    AmazonCognitoIdentity cognitoClient = AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.builder()
            .withCredentials(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
                @Override
                public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                    return new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
                }

                @Override
                public void refresh() {

                }
            }).withRegion(EU_CENTRAL_1.getName()).build();

    String identityId = cognitoClient.getId(new GetIdRequest()
            .withIdentityPoolId(identityPoolId))
            .getIdentityId();

    Credentials cognitoCreds = cognitoClient
            .getCredentialsForIdentity(
                    new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest()
                            .withIdentityId(identityId))
            .getCredentials();

    AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
    signer.setServiceName("execute-api");
    signer.setRegionName(EU_CENTRAL_1.getName());

    AmazonHttpClient amazonHttpClient =
            new AmazonHttpClient(new ClientConfiguration());
    Request r = new DefaultRequest("execute-api");
    r.setEndpoint(new URI(endpoint));
    r.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
    BasicSessionCredentials basicCreds = new BasicSessionCredentials(
            cognitoCreds.getAccessKeyId(),
            cognitoCreds.getSecretKey(),
            cognitoCreds.getSessionToken());

    signer.sign(r, basicCreds);

    amazonHttpClient
            .requestExecutionBuilder()
            .request(r)
            .execute(logResponse());
}

private static HttpResponseHandler<Void> logResponse() {
    return new HttpResponseHandler<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void handle(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("response code = " + httpResponse.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("response headers = " + httpResponse.getHeaders());
            System.out.println("response content = " + new String(bytes(httpResponse.getContent())));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean needsConnectionLeftOpen() {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

It works, but boy is that ugly code.  What am I missing?  How can this be done more cleanly?